# How to call a component's method from the main method?

Tags: spring-boot

I m new to springboot

I created a component :

```
@Component
public class Article {

    File xml = new File(Constante.ARTICLE_XML);
    static File out = new File(Constante.ARTICLE_CSV + "out_article.csv");

    public synchronized void process() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        Thread th = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    .....
                }
            }
        };
        th.start();
    }
    .....
}
```

Here is the main method :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.axian.oxalys.*")
@PropertySource({"file:${app.home}/application.properties"})
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {



    }
}
```

How can I call the component's method process() from the `main` method ?

Comment: If you simply want to execute the components method after startup, you could use an ApplicationRunner, see https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-applicationrunner-and-commandlinerunne

Comment: Ok , I created the `CommandLineRunner` class. But now how can I use it in the `main` method ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For testing purposes it's okay to implement CommandLineRunner interface in your application class.

Then, since `Article` is a spring bean, you can autowire it and simply call the method.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.axian.oxalys.*")
@PropertySource({"file:${app.home}/application.properties"})
public class App implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private Article article

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args)
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        article.process();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If your goal is to have some logic running on startup, you can create a new bean, implementing either the `CommandLineRunner` or `ApplicationRunner` interface. This will automatically execute the `run()` method on startup, and you don't have to do anything else. For example:

```
@Bean
public CommandLineRunner runOnStartup(Article article) {
    return args -> article.process();
}
```

If you explicitly want to call a method within your `main` method (you probably shouldn't), then you can do so by obtaining a reference to the `Environment`. Normally if you have a Spring boot application, you have a `SpringApplication.run()` statement already, which you can use like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    Article article =  context.getBean(Article.class);
    article.process();
}
```